# Create NSTableView cells without XIB or Storyboard cells

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nstableviewcell

I'm using a storyboard to place my table and set constraints, but I want all of the columns to be defined via code.  I have a set of like 15 columns that I always add to 6 or 7 tables, so it's much easier to just do that from code.

I can add all the NSTableColumn without issue, but I can't figure out how to handle the `tableView(:viewForTableColumn:row:)` method as there's no configured cell for the `makeViewWithdentifier(:owner:)` call.

Comment: I answered a question a couple of months ago which dealt with creating [a working ``NSTableView`` entirely in code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33992756/is-it-possible-to-create-a-view-based-nstableview-purely-in-code/34131404#34131404). The answer itself probably isn't sufficient to get you where you want to go, but one of the comments contains a link to an associated demo project which may help you.

Comment: Thanks, that was perfect!