# NSTableView won't call viewForTableColumn

Tags: swift, cocoa, swift4, nstableview, nstableviewcell

I am trying to build a table view without interface builder from scratch in my Cocoa app and my `viewForTableColumn` method refuses to get called.

My table view is created using this code.

```
let tableView: NSTableView = {
    let table = NSTableView(frame: .zero)
    table.headerView = nil
    table.addTableColumn(NSTableColumn(identifier: .column))

    return table
}()
```

I also have this extension for the `NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier` class

```
extension NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier {
    static let cell = NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier("cell")
    static let column = NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier("column")
}
```

My view controller is implementing `NSTableViewDataSource` and `NSTableViewDelegate` and they are set in the `viewDidLoad` method. The table view is also into a scroll view.

```
let scrollView = NSScrollView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.scrollView.documentView = self.tableView
    self.scrollView.hasVerticalScroller = true
    self.view.addSubview(self.scrollView)

    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.reloadData() // To make sure the method would be called.
}
```

The value returned from the `numberOfRows` method is bigger than `0` and is executed.

From my understanding the following method should be called with the row parameter ranging from 0 to the value returned by `numberOfRows` but it's never being called.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
    guard let view = self.tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: .cell, owner: self) as? NSTableCellView else {
        return nil
    }

    // set the text/font for the view

    return view
}
```

I've also tried using `dataCellFor` and `rowViewForRow` but none of them is getting called.

EDIT:

I've checked the frame of my elements to make sure the table view and the rows were visible.

[image: view hierarchy]

Comment: An invisible table view doesn't ask for views. What is the the frame of `scrollView`?

Comment: The frame is set to the size of the window, setting the background color to red confirms that it is visible.

Comment: Are the frame of the table view and the width of the column also ok? If you capture the view hierarchy, is the table view visible?

Comment: I've added a picture of the view hierarchy, the blue view is the `scrollView` and the red is the `tableView`

Comment: I tried your code (added `self.scrollView.frame = self.view.bounds` and `numberOfRowsInTableView`) and `viewForTableColumn` is called. It returns `nil`.

Comment: Do you think it could be something external in my setup? The code should work like you mentioned. This view is in a second `NSWindow` but it probably should still work just fine.

Comment: I answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33992756/is-it-possible-to-create-a-view-based-nstableview-purely-in-code) a while back - perhaps it can help

Comment: @PaulPatterson Your code looks a lot like mine, not sure what would be the cause of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to one of the comments beneath your question `tableView(_:viewFor:row:)` *is* being called, it's just returning `nil`. This makes sense given your implementation of that method. When `makeViewWithIdentifier` fails you need to manually create the relevant view and return *it*, rather than returning `nil`. As such your implementation should look something like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {

    if let recycledView = self.tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: .cell, owner: self) as? NSTableCellView {
        return recycledView
    } else {
        // create view from scratch
        let newCell = NSTableCellView()
        newCell.identifier = NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier.cell
        // customise here...
        return newCell
    }
}
```

Look again at the link I provided in my comment, you'll see that that implementation never returns `nil` from this method.

Comment: I tried putting a print and a breakpoint in there and none of it was triggered. I've fix my problem now, still not sure what was wrong, I rewrote the entire `NSWindow` the only difference is that I took out the `NSViewController`. Thanks for your answer.